# How to use variables with Recordset!

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, variables, recordset

My problem is the following:

I need to assign a value to the recordset. The problem isthat I need to use a variable. So, instead of write this

```
MyRecordSet![field_name]
```

I need to write this

```
MyRecordSet![variable_name]
```

This all look simple even to me, until I find out that inside the brackets there are no quotation marks to separate strings of text from variable names. Therefore, I can't distinguish them.

Please, guys, help me! I've tried everything you can imagine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MyRecordSet.Fields(variablename)
```

Comment: Man, that worked as miracle. Thank, buddy. I will sign up just to "thumb you up".

Comment: Man, sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to "Vote Up". Apologies.

Comment: The Fields collection is the default collection, so all you really need is `MyRecordSet(variablename)`.`